# changing wallpaper c++ ive tried multiple ways

Tags: c++

```
string s = "C:\\ok.bmp";
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)s.c_str(), SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

This doesnt work ^^ and the ok.bmp is inside of the folder!

Answer (score 0):

Most builds are Unicode nowadays, so try with a Unicode string:

```
wstring ws = L"C:\\ok.bmp";
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, ws.data(), SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

(by using `std::wstring::data()`, you don't need the cast).